# Controlling a 10V PWM LED driver (MEAN WELL HLG-185H-C1400B) with Raspberry Pi

Tags: led, pwm, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project where I need to dim a set of LEDs by utilizing the PWM signal on a [Mean Well HLG-185H-C1400B](https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-single-output-led-driver-constant-current-cc-hlg--185h--c1400b).

As a beginner, I am seeking guidance on how to control a 10V PWM LED using a Raspberry Pi. Initially, I considered using a logic level converter between the RPI PWM pin and the LED driver, but I am uncertain if this is the correct approach. I am also having  difficulty finding a 3.3V → 10V converter, as most available options seem to be for 3.3V → 5V conversion.

I would greatly appreciate any pointers or suggestions to steer me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: There is an internal 10v pull up in the driver, so you can simply put a transistor between+ and -. Here is a simple solution in this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563666/meanwell-pwm-dimming